# Is there a Flutter package to calculate and draw the shortest path in a map that uses Mercator projection?

Tags: flutter, dart, lib

I am trying to draw the shortest path between two cities inside the flutter_map plugin. flutter_map uses OpenStreetMaps which displays the map in Mercator projection and has a functionality called `polyline`, which allows to draw a line between a path of points. Now if I draw a line from one city to another city this shows up as a straight line on the map, which of course is not the shortest path, because of the projection.

After some googling I found stuff like [this](https://planetcalc.com/713/?license=1) that looks quite math heavy and rather difficult to implement. Therefore I am wondering if there is a library that provides methods to calculate the shortest path in a Mercator projection or if there is another way to do that, that I am not aware of.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess at "no". This seems like a very niche application and the Google Maps subsection of community packages is fairly barren as it is. I'm not much of a cartographer, but I wonder why you arrived at a rhumb line as your solution. That is a line (or, more specifically, an arc) that maintains a constant bearing relative to magnetic north, which is not going to be the shortest path to anything. What you need to do is calculate the great-circle distance between the two points and then project that arc through the same Mercator projection as the map. (No one said it would be easy...)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The issue is that I want to provide offline ability for my app, so Google Maps is not an option and Flutter Mapbox unfortunately only supports Android until now.